# Linux filter which convert data coming from pipe to chunked transfer encoding

Tags: http, ruby, pipe, data-transfer, cgi

I usually use Open3.popen3 in my Ruby CGI scripts to start a Linux command, parse its standard output and converting the bytes to the chunked transfer encoding  ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding )

```
 th<<Thread.new do
         counter=0
           while data=stdout.read(64*1024)
            STDOUT.puts "#{data.size.to_s(16)};"
            STDOUT.print data
            STDOUT.puts
            counter+=data.size
           end
           STDOUT.puts "0"
           STDOUT.puts "Content-Length: #{counter}"
           STDOUT.puts
end
th.join
```

I wonder if maybe already is there a Linux command line utility / filter which do this particular job: counting the bytes, printing the chunks with the proper headers, and the closing footer with the counted content length. So I simply could pipe the command output to that filter, no need for Open3.popen3, I think conversion would be faster.